# Exchange mgmt shell: get sender email adress fron all mail in public folder

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server, export-to-csv, public-folders

[prolog]
I have a Exchange 2013 server running. Within a public folder (called: "events") there are a few subfolders. These folders are called "winter 2015", "summer 2015" and so on. After an event, the participants can send a eMail to take part in a contest.

[question]
I need to export all sender-addresses to an CSV-file, to send a invertation for the next event. I want to use the *exchange management shell* (or Powershell shell) to do this. I stuck with finding the right command.

...so far - when I use:

```
Get-PublicFolderItemStatistics “\events\winter 2015” | fl
```

I get this for every eMail:

```
RunspaceId           : 4171018f-57d4-4ba6-90ca-7002097d3e98
Subject              : bike contest winter 2015
PublicFolderName     : \events\winter 2015
LastModificationTime : 31.07.2015 07:14:52
CreationTime         : 31.07.2015 07:14:52
HasAttachments       : False
ItemType             : IPM.Note
MessageSize          : 11.51 KB (11,790 bytes)
Identity             : corp.domain.com/DE/PF-A100\RgAAAAC33A2/VFsDS7P7bMLtt06fBwDaAlX8hPjaQq/VvypRTeGhAAAAu8plAADaAlX8hPjaQq/VvypRTeGhAAAq8bWeAAAJ
MailboxOwnerId       : corp.domain.com/DE/PF-A100
IsValid              : True
ObjectState          : New
```

Do I have to use the *Identity* to access the details of each eMail? Or is there a better way? What is the right command? Would it be possible to create a PS-Script with paramters to automitic run it two times a year?

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to get this done thru a simple PS script to call EWS API and pull the Item Level information of the event Folder and aggregate based on the sender.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dd633642(v=exchg.80).aspx
This link would help with the EWS API , GetItem Call.

And for EWS thru Powershell, the script in this blog [PS EWS reference](https://seanonit.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/using-powershell-and-ews-to-monitor-a-mailbox/)
could help.